# Bitcoin Address generation

Tags: address, sha256

The [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses)  says this:

---

### How to create Bitcoin Address

0 - Having a private ECDSA key

```
18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725
```

1 - Take the corresponding public key generated with it

```
0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
```

2 - Perform SHA-256 hashing on the public key

```
600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408
```

---

but when I run a sha256 on

```
0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
```

I don't get

```
600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408
```

What I get is

```
32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo -n  "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6"
| sha256sum
```

Gives: 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce

```
echo "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6"
| xxd -r -p /proc/self/fd/0 | sha256sum
```

Gives: 600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408

Conclusion: You hashed an ASCII representation of the public key in hexadecimal rather than the public key itself.

Answer (score 4):

Use must use SHA256 on array of bytes, not on a hex-string representation.